# I can't allocate a dataframe to this variable - Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to rearrange the columns of a data frame in spark scala with this code

```
def performTransformations(commonArgs: Map[String, Any], dataDf: Dataset[Row]): Dataset[Row] = {  
   // Create local var as a copy of data 
   var data = dataDf  
   *all the transformations here*       
   val data2 = data.select(reorderedColNames: _*)      
   data = data2   
}
```

the reorderdColNames is an array that has all the columns in the order I want.

But I am getting this error

```
error: type mismatch;
[ERROR]  found   : Unit
[ERROR]  required: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
```

How can I manage this? Thanks

I have tried to arrange the columns with other methods but I wasn't able.

Comment: How do you declare `data` initially? Please post a minimal reproducible example

Comment: `def performTransformations(commonArgs: Map[String, Any], dataDf: Dataset[Row]): Dataset[Row] = {

// Create local var as a copy of data
    var data = dataDf

*all the transformations here*

    val data2 = data.select(reorderedColNames: _*)
    data = data2

}
`

Comment: Edit your question and add it in there, we can't understand without new lines

Comment: And post an example that one can actually copy and paste to reproduce your exact error please

Comment: Why would you even want to reassign to the variable? why not just return it? there should be no compile-time problem with this code: `data.select(reorderedColNames: _*)`. The problem probably is that you need to return the data, and `data = data.select(reorderedColNames: _*)` is a Unit.

Comment: This is still not a minimal reproducible example: `dataDf` is not defined, `reorderedColNames` is not defined, the transformations you talk about are not defined... I can't reproduce your error without first trying to make your code work by defining all missing variables by myself. Next time you ask a question, make sure to create a code that people can copy paste to get the same error as you without needing to deal with all undefined variables (people will be much more willing to help if the error is easy to reproduce than if they have to figure out how to reproduce it by tweaking your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, the problem is that your function is defined to return `Dataset[Row]` but in fact it returns `Unit` as the last statement of the function is a variable assignment (`data = data2`).

Change your function to:

```
def performTransformations(commonArgs: Map[String, Any], dataDf: Dataset[Row]): Dataset[Row] = {  
    // Create local var as a copy of data     
    var data = dataDf  
    // all the transformations here    
    data.select(reorderedColNames: _*)   
}
```

Comment: Additional note: using a `var` is generally not a good practice (except in some quite rare cases), so I would stick to a `val` as much as possible

Comment: Agree, just copied the original function with minimal changes. Since I don't know what kind of transformation are done in the function, decided to leave it as is. But you are absolutely right.

Comment: Hi, I am new to scala and after a couple hours I could make my entire code work and this was very helpful. this function is a part of a data transformation pipeline with scala. The transformations are some castings and time zones transformations but I thought they were not relevant in here. Thank you both.